# Saving Excel files to Sharepoint using VBA prompts to save a copy of the file

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I've inherited a solution that I'm maintaining that is essentially a single excel file (we'll call it the 'master' file) with VBA that calls other excel files to do the following:

1. Update Data
2. Update Pivot Tables
3. Save the file to a SharePoint location

Recently, when I try to run the 'master' excel file I've started to be prompted to save a "Copy of File 'FileName' " instead of the file just overwriting the existing version. I can remove the "copy of" prefix to the file name an overwrite the old version. The code that the master file is using has this statement:

```
Workbooks(sReportWorkbook).Close SaveChanges:=True
```

This solution has worked for over a year before this started. I'm familiar with VB (not VBA as much) and SharePoint but haven't worked with either in quite some time. If it helps, I'm using Office 365 (2013 Excel) and Sharepoint 2013.

What would cause the dialog window to show when the file is being saved? Please let me know if additional details are required.

Comment: You can wrap that line in `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and then after that code turn it back on with `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`.

Comment: Great! I'll try that.

Comment: No luck @Soulfire I'm still receiving a prompt. I added the code you mentioned before (FALSE) and after (TRUE) the statement I quoted in my question (line above and line below) but the results are the same.

Is it possible that permissions on SharePoint would cause this? What is strange is that I can overwrite the file when I save it as 'the same name' - it's just that the VBA will no longer overwrite the file without prompting to save a copy.